# Score obtained from cross_val_score is RMSE or MSE?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, random-forest, cross-validation

I am using following code:-

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = regressor, X=X,y=y, cv =10)
accuracies.mean()
```

This mean value is RMSE or MSE ?

EDIT:- I am using random forest regression. In Scikit learn documentation they describe it as accuracy. How can i relate it with RMSE or MSE

Comment: What model? You have included the `random-forest` tag, but please clarify this in the question itself.

Comment: Hello, look into documentation - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html . Provide scorer, or read documentation of your regressor's class

Answer (score 10):

It is actually neither RMSE nor MSE. If you look into the documentation of [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score), you can see that it has a parameter `scoring` for which it says:

> If None, the estimator’s default scorer (if available) is used.

In your case, this means it will use the default scorer of the `RandomForestRegressor`. When you look up the documentation for its [`.score()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html?highlight=randomforest#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score) method, it tells you:

> Return the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.

This means you computed the mean **R^2**. If you want to change this behavior, you have to specify the `scoring` parameter of `cross_val_score`. Options can be found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter).

Answer (score 1):

Scores obtained from cross_val_score regressor are by default 'r2' (R-squared), if you want to get RMSE you can use 'neg_root_mean_squared_error' and then change the sign. Sklearn sets a negative score because an optimization process usually seeks to maximize the score. But in this case, by maximizing it, we would be seeking to increase the error. I think, this was resolved by changing the sign of the score. If you would like to use other metrics, you can find them at [scikit-learn page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html).

Here is how you could get the RMSE scores

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator = regressor, X=X,y=y,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv =10)
accuracies.mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the cross-validation score in RMSE or MSE, try this

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
nrmse = cross_val_score(estimator = regressor, X=X,y=y,scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error', cv =10)
print(nrmse.mean()*-1)

nmse = cross_val_score(estimator = regressor, X=X,y=y,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv =10)
print(nmse.mean()*-1)
```

The following code gives you all the scoring options:

```
sorted(sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys())
```

Which gives you:

> ['accuracy',  'adjusted_mutual_info_score',  'adjusted_rand_score',
> 'average_precision',  'balanced_accuracy',  'completeness_score',
> 'explained_variance',  'f1',  'f1_macro',  'f1_micro',  'f1_samples',
> 'f1_weighted',  'fowlkes_mallows_score',  'homogeneity_score',
> 'jaccard',  'jaccard_macro',  'jaccard_micro',  'jaccard_samples',
> 'jaccard_weighted',  'max_error',  'mutual_info_score',
> 'neg_brier_score',  'neg_log_loss',  'neg_mean_absolute_error',
> 'neg_mean_absolute_percentage_error',  'neg_mean_gamma_deviance',
> 'neg_mean_poisson_deviance',  'neg_mean_squared_error',
> 'neg_mean_squared_log_error',  'neg_median_absolute_error',
> 'neg_root_mean_squared_error',  'normalized_mutual_info_score',
> 'precision',  'precision_macro',  'precision_micro',
> 'precision_samples',  'precision_weighted',  'r2',  'rand_score',
> 'recall',  'recall_macro',  'recall_micro',  'recall_samples',
> 'recall_weighted',  'roc_auc',  'roc_auc_ovo',
> 'roc_auc_ovo_weighted',  'roc_auc_ovr',  'roc_auc_ovr_weighted',
> 'top_k_accuracy',  'v_measure_score']